# mDNS in the context of a DNS

Tags: networking, security, vpn, firewall

Yesterday we have been discussing mDNS in the context of a lecture at the University. We did not exactly come to a result and I can't stop to think about it. The project in the lecture was about configuring a Unix (in this case OSX) system in order to enable privacy enhanced surfing in the internet. To do so, we configured a VPN channel to Sweded that will take all our traffic and configured a firewall to disallow any other traffic. One aspect of the exercise has been to achieve that the system should stay usable. However, when simply blocking all the other traffic, OSX has not been able to print any longer as it uses mDNS/bonjour for printer discovery. So, we came into a longish discussion about whether we should allow mDNS traffic. One group of people argued that we should disallow it as it could bring a leak into the design of anonymous surfing as: 1) In theory the system is also allowed to query standard DNS queries via mDNS if there is no other DNS server available 2) As it is a multicast scheme, we cannot limit the traffic to local networks. The other group basically argued that we should enable mDNS as it would only be used for local services by the system.

Well, the discussion is over but I'm very curious whether the hardcore network experts here in the forum have an opinion about this:

So: Does enabling mDNS on such a VPN based system impact (theoretically) the privacy/anonymity? What do you think?

Thanks for your opinions Norbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mDNS uses a multicast address that's only valid on the local link. Routers don't forward it. You cannot use IGMP to ask a router to forward the next hop's mDNS traffic to you. So if you trust your local LAN, leaving 5353/UDP open will be okay.

By the way, although it's easy to use Bonjour when setting up OS X printing, you can also manually input the IP address of the printer, avoiding Bonjour.

Comment: For extra paranoia, you could configure the firewall to only allow port 5353 traffic to/from local addresses (including 169.254.0.0/16) and the specific local multicast addresses mDNS uses (224.0.0.251 for IPv4 and ff02::fb for IPv6).